How do I configure i18n with django rosetta in react?
I'm writing the frontend code using react. I need to change the language on the site using Django. I don't know where to start. Should i use i18next?
How can I configure if I need to use it


import i18n from "i18next";
import detector from "i18next-browser-languagedetector";
import backend from "i18next-http-backend";
import { initReactI18next } from "react-i18next";

i18n
  .use(detector)
  .use(backend)
  .use(initReactI18next) // passes i18n down to react-i18next
  .init({
    fallbackLng: "en", // use en if detected lng is not available
    saveMissing: true // send not translated keys to endpoint
  });

export default i18n;




